# NPM node-sass error in Laravel v5.6.26 - Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '**/node_modules/node-sass/vendor'

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, node-sass

Encountered this exact error on my production server: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1579

**My production server:**
Ubuntu 17.10 x64
nginx/1.12.1
PHP 7.1.17
node v6.11.4
Laravel 5.6.26
npm 3.5.2
node-sass: 4.9.1

Have the same codebase running without a problem locally on a Homestead box. However, getting this fatal error on my production server. I have tried destroying & rebuilding the node_modules directory, also the suggested commands below.

`npm update`
`npm install`
`nodejs node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js`
`npm rebuild node-sass`

I also tried to rollback to a 'node-sass' package to a version that didn't include a vendor directory, to no avail.

Any ideas for a fix of this package? Or would it be better to switch to another sass compiler without issues?